# Error when opening Android Virtual Device Manager

Tags: android, eclipse, device

i get the folllowing error-messages when opening the Android Virtual Device Manager. Does someone know what is causing this?

[SDK Manager] Error: Error parsing D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702_\sdk\system-images\android-20\android-wear\x86\devices.xml

[SDK Manager] Error: Error parsing D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702_\sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml

[SDK Manager] Error: Error parsing D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702_\sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\x86\devices.xml

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Now, when I open my Eclipse the following error occurs:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [SDK Manager] Error: Error parsing
>   D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702_\sdk\system-images\android-20\android-wear\x86\devices.xml

It seems you are trying to create AVD using **Android Wear API**. Download other API like 22, 23 and try creating AVD. It will work.

Comment: Do I have to deinstall something? I'm just updating API 21 but I already have complete API 22 and API 23.

Comment: When you create AVD, choose API 22 or 23. BTW Are you working with Wear?

Comment: Nope, I always tested with usb-cabel. But now I want to test local web services and need to use android virtual devices.

Comment: @Jolle Then create a new AVD or edit the existing AVD with API 22/23. Try it and let me know :)

Comment: Nice, you are right! I get it started but I think my laptop is too slow because it needs a lot of time to get ready. Thanks anyway :) !

Comment: I have some issues on eclipse start now. Edited my question above!